# how do i store value using sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code. I want to store sel1.value for redirect to subdomain.
This code is not storing sel1.value. I set alert for cookie and that i am getting but how to store this?

```js
function alertCookie(puser) {
  document.cookie = "username=" + puser + ";domain=*.ixxco.coop;";
  sessionStorage.setItem("username", sel1.value);
  alert(puser);
  window.open('https://xxxxxxxx:3500/chat.html', 'Saathi ML BOT', 'width=500,height=650,left=900');
}
```

```css
.chat-btn img {
  width: 100%;
}

.chat-btn {
  width: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.text1 {
  color: #e49012;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: .2;
  position: relative;
  top: -14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #e7ffca;
}
```

```html
<label for="sel1" class="header-lbl">Party: </label>
<select id="sel1" class="header-cntrl form-control">
  <option value="NRKT01017" selected>NRKT01017- Limited</option>

</select>

<div class="chat-btn">
  <img src="images/chat-btn.png" alt="image" onclick=alertCookie(sel1.value);>
  <span class="text1">Chat Assistance</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML was not valid. Also you want `document.getElementById("sel1").value`

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: ``sel1.value`` is not defined inside your session set. Use ``sessionStorage.setItem("username", puser);`` instead of **sel1.value**

Comment: `sel1` is not defined in your function, so  `sel1.value` won't exist.

Comment: `sessionStorage.setItem("username", puser);` is also not working - @NotABot

Comment: @subhajitsaha Which value you want to store? **NRKT01017** of ``select``?

Comment: yes . i want to store NRKT01017 @NotABot

Comment: @subhajitsaha Then it won't work with your approach, as in  ``onclick=alertCookie(sel1.value);`` **sel1** is not defined.           To solve this first you need to get the value of the **selected option** then you can session store that value.

Comment: i am getting value of the **selected option** from puser `document.cookie = "username=" + puser + ";domain=*.iffco.coop;";` @NotABot

Comment: can you please edit my code ? @NotABot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use event listener

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector(".chat-btn").addEventListener("click", alertCookies);
  document.getElementById("sel1").addEventListener("change", selectedSel);
})

function selectedSel() {
  console.log(this.value); // or whatever you want when the select changes
}

function alertCookies() {
  const puser = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
  console.log(puser);
  if (puser) { // uncomment when on your server
    // document.cookie = "username=" + puser + ";domain=*.ixxco.coop;";
    // sessionStorage.setItem("username", puser);
    //  window.open('https://xxxxxxxx:3500/chat.html', 'Saathi ML BOT', 'width=500,height=650,left=900');
  }
}
```

```css
.chat-btn img {
  width: 100%;
}

.chat-btn {
  width: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.text1 {
  color: #e49012;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: .2;
  position: relative;
  top: -14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #e7ffca;
}
```

```html
<label for="sel1" class="header-lbl">Party: </label>
<select id="sel1" class="header-cntrl form-control">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="NRKT01017">NRKT01017- Limited</option>
</select>

<div class="chat-btn">
  <img src="images/chat-btn.png" alt="Click Me">
  <span class="text1">Chat Assistance</span>
</div>
```